# Multiplications a*b vs a*0: execution time

Tags: python, multiplication, execution-time, microbenchmark

Action 1: Multiplication of a random number a with another random number b
Action 2: Multiplication of the same number a with 0

I did a small experiment to see which of these actions has the smallest execution time. So I wrote the small program below that does Action 1 a large number of times measuring its total execution time and repeates the same for Action 2 to see the smallest execution time between the two. I repeat the above 100 times to create more reliable results.

Run the program to see that for some reason Action 1 is faster tha Action 2 most of the times (around 75%). What could be the explanation for something like that?

```
import time
import numpy as np

def compare_execution_times(a, b):
    # Measure the execution time of multiplication with non-zero b
    start_time = time.time()
    for _ in range(1000000):  # Perform multiplication a large number of times
        result = a * b
    end_time = time.time()
    first_execution_time = end_time - start_time
    
    # Measure the execution time of multiplication with zero b
    start_time = time.time()
    for _ in range(1000000):  # Perform multiplication a large number of times
        result = a * 0
    end_time = time.time()
    second_execution_time = end_time - start_time
    
    return first_execution_time < second_execution_time

count_true = 0
count_false = 0
for _ in range(100):
    a = np.random.rand()  # Generate random a
    b = np.random.rand()  # Generate random b
    if compare_execution_times(a, b):
        count_true += 1
    else:
        count_false += 1

print("\nNumber of times first execution was smaller:", count_true)
print("Number of times second execution was smaller:", count_false)
```

Edit: One mistake that I made is that in Action 2 the `0` is `int` but it should be `0.0`, thus `float`, for a better comparison (see the answer below).

Comment: With `a` being a float, I'm pretty sure that `a * 0` is going to involve a runtime conversion of zero from int to float; nothing like that is necessary in the `a * b` case.  `a * 0.0` might be a fairer test.

Comment: You are correct, I didn't notice the different types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `time.time` is terrible for measuring fine-grained performance. The `timeit` module, or the `%timeit` magic in IPython, handles a *lot* of small errors that can creep in with naive timing.
2. You're comparing with floating point values, not Python `int`s, for your `a` and `b`, so type conversions are getting involved only when multiplying by `0`, but not by `b`. It wouldn't surprise me that mismatched types would be more expensive than matched types. Changing your zero literal to `0.` or `0.0` would likely reduce the runtime for zeroes a bit.

If you want a legitimate comparison, here's an example using pure Python `float`s:

```
In [1]: %%timeit import random; a, b = random.random(), random.random()
   ...: a*b
   ...:
   ...:
13.6 ns ± 0.13 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000,000 loops each)

In [2]: %%timeit import random; a, b = random.random(), random.random()
   ...: a*0.0
   ...:
   ...:
13.2 ns ± 0.105 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000,000 loops each)
```

(note I used `0.0` so the literal was a `float` literal, not `int`) and with pure Python `int`s:

```
In [3]: %%timeit import random; a, b = random.randrange(16), random.randrange(16)
    ...: a*b
    ...:
    ...:
11.4 ns ± 0.986 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000,000 loops each)

In [4]: %%timeit import random; a, b = random.randrange(16), random.randrange(16)
   ...: a*0
   ...:
   ...:
11.3 ns ± 0.33 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000,000 loops each)
```

In both cases, multiplying by zero was slightly faster, but not enough to matter (in the second case, the timings were so close I suspect they're statistically insignificant; I'd only see a win if I'd allowed the `randrange` to go higher than 16, causing the integer math to produce new `int`s, rather than pulling from the small `int` cache).

Comment: presumably multiplying anything by zero can be ignored?

Comment: 1) Would it be a good strategy to run the import plus the random selections before and only measure time for the a*b / a*0 ?

Comment: 2) So what happens "internally"? Does the compiler see the second multiplication as "unneccessary" and skips it by simply giving a zero?

Comment: @MitchWheat: CPython's optimizer is *incredibly* limited. It doesn't know what `a` is, so `a*0` could produce *anything* (e.g. if `a` is a `str`, it produces `''`, if it's a `list`, `[]`, etc.). Even if you used `0.0` (which won't work in those contexts), `a` could be some arbitrary user-defined type and produce something nuts. The most modern CPython will recognize when a particular bytecode is only executed against floats at runtime, and eventually self-optimize to a code path that is more specific to `float`s, but it still makes a new `float` (almost) all the time.

Comment: @user1198483: I doubt using `0.0` is actually faster even in the two `float` variable case (I was running tests on a laptop, and while I disabled all power-saving measures that I could, laptops still tend to have some engaged no matter what). On rerunning the microbenchmarks on a workstation running 3.12.0 (the timings in the answer were from a 3.11.6 build), the two cases were indistinguishable; sometimes one would win, sometimes the other, with both exhibiting a range of values constituting about 10% of the total time.

Comment: @user1198483: Internally, AFAICT, for the `float` case, it's treating both cases the same. It loads `b` from the locals, and `0.0` from the constants, but both of those are simple array accesses; `0.0` *might* be a little slower in larger code simply because having loaded `a`, `b` is definitely in cache (even if the object isn't), while the constants array hasn't been touched. Once they're loaded though, the code path for both is *identical*, Python does nothing to optimize multiplying by `0.0` at all (it *could* handle `0.0` by returning an alias of the input w/o allocating, it doesn't).

Comment: @ShadowRanger if it's treating both cases the same then why is the second case (a*0.0) slightly faster than the first one (a*b)? (the difference might be small but this seems to happen systematically, from my tests approximately 90% of the times).

Comment: @user1198483: Like I said, when I reran on a workstation, `0.0` tended to lose slightly more often than it won. The test timing is too variable based on allocator state, cache state, etc. `LOAD_FAST` and `LOAD_CONST` are nigh identical (both array lookups, but in theory a pair of `LOAD_FAST`s might be a *little* faster by being more cache friendly), and the fact that `0.0` might be handled more efficiently by the CPU are the only sources of reliable difference, and none of them should matter. The results are too close to draw reliable conclusions.

Comment: @user1198483: As for why your specific, hand-rolled test, fixed to use `0.0` instead of `0`, might have `0.0` win, like I said, hand-rolled benchmarking code is uniformly garbage. You always run the tests in the same order, you use `range` for repetitions instead of `itertools.repeat` (the former constantly allocates and frees `int`s even though you don't need them, the latter would just return the same object over and over w/o allocator churn), you didn't disable the garbage collector (which runs at technically predictable, but non-obvious, intervals, which could affect one test more), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Fwiw, here's a disassembly of your function:

```
  7           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (time)
              2 LOAD_METHOD              0 (time)
              4 CALL_METHOD              0
              6 STORE_FAST               2 (start_time)

  8           8 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (range)
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (1000000)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             14 GET_ITER
        >>   16 FOR_ITER                 6 (to 30)
             18 STORE_FAST               3 (_)

  9          20 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             22 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
             24 BINARY_MULTIPLY
             26 STORE_FAST               4 (result)
             28 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            8 (to 16)

 10     >>   30 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (time)
             32 LOAD_METHOD              0 (time)
             34 CALL_METHOD              0
             36 STORE_FAST               5 (end_time)

 11          38 LOAD_FAST                5 (end_time)
             40 LOAD_FAST                2 (start_time)
             42 BINARY_SUBTRACT
             44 STORE_FAST               6 (first_execution_time)

 14          46 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (time)
             48 LOAD_METHOD              0 (time)
             50 CALL_METHOD              0
             52 STORE_FAST               2 (start_time)

 15          54 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (range)
             56 LOAD_CONST               1 (1000000)
             58 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             60 GET_ITER
        >>   62 FOR_ITER                 6 (to 76)
             64 STORE_FAST               3 (_)

 16          66 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             68 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
             70 BINARY_MULTIPLY
             72 STORE_FAST               4 (result)
             74 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           31 (to 62)

 17     >>   76 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (time)
             78 LOAD_METHOD              0 (time)
             80 CALL_METHOD              0
             82 STORE_FAST               5 (end_time)

 18          84 LOAD_FAST                5 (end_time)
             86 LOAD_FAST                2 (start_time)
             88 BINARY_SUBTRACT
             90 STORE_FAST               7 (second_execution_time)

 20          92 LOAD_FAST                6 (first_execution_time)
             94 LOAD_FAST                7 (second_execution_time)
             96 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
```

I'm not sure about how LOAD_FAST and LOAD_CONST compare in terms of performance, but there is at least a difference in how the code gets put together.

Comment: I think that the most important difference is (as stated by others before) that 0 is integer and not float, so there needs to be a "conversion" before the multiplication.

Comment: Both `LOAD_FAST` and `LOAD_CONST` boil down to a single C array access (through pointers in the stack frame object). When both arrays are hot in cache (which would happen quickly), access times are identical. `LOAD_CLOSURE` would be a little slower (it has to chase a couple more pointers to reach the value), and `LOAD_GLOBAL` is theoretically slower (it has to check 1-2 `dict`s), except in modern Python it uses a cache hidden in the bytecode, and if the `dict`s in question have not been updated, it doesn't actually perform any hashing or `dict` lookup at all.